# pass input array data to http from ngModel in ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic3, angular6

I am trying to develop a mobile app with below design..

[image]

When click on the continue button I need to send data to http api like

```
data = {
 {'product':'Salt','quantity',23,'price',4567},
 {'product':'Sugar','quantity',12,'price',21}, 
 {'product':'Egg','quantity',2,'price',64}, 
 {'product':'Milk','quantity',8,'price',243}
};
```

I tried many answers in stack and its not working.

```
 <ion-list>
    <div class="itemPro" *ngFor="let product of products;let i = index;">
      <div class="prduct">{{product.name}}</div>
      <div class="quanty"><input [(ngModel)]="quanty_i" type="number"/></div>
      <div class="amt"><input [(ngModel)]="amt_i" type="number"/></div>
    </div>
  </ion-list>

 <div class="w80">
      <button class="big-btn" ion-button full (click)="continueToReview()">Continue</button>
  </div>

 continueToReview(){
   console.log(this.product.quantity);
 }
```

How can I solve this issue with angular array systems ?

[image]

Comment: is that products is object of Objects or an Array...?

Comment: @ganesh045 Updated question with products array. please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

[***Working Demo***](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-twstim?file=src/app/app.component.html)

```
<div class="itemPro" *ngFor="let product of products;let i = index;">
  <div class="prduct">{{product.product}}</div>
  <div class="quanty"><input [(ngModel)]="product.quantity" type="number"/></div>
  <div class="amt"><input [(ngModel)]="product.price" type="number"/></div>
</div>
```

since you have multiple product items but you are looking for only selected product,

we need to move button in to `ion-list` in order to get index of the Array.

```
 <div class="itemPro" *ngFor="let product of products;let i = index;">
  ...
  <div class="w80">
      <button class="big-btn" ion-button full (click)="continueToReview(i)">Continue</button>
  </div>
  ... 
 </div>
```

**Component.ts**

```
continueToReview(index) {
   const selectedProd = this.products[index];
}
```

Comment: May I know that how can I access these variables in my on click function ? I wan to accept the input of quantity and price..

Comment: I have not seen any `click()` fn in your code, is that on first div...

Comment: Updated question, Can you please recheck ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but can ask that is it require every single line click button right ? is there any way to do it with a single submit button to capture the values ?